# Ambiguous overload error when using conversion function

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

I am trying to understand overloading resolution in C++ through the books listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). One such example that i wrote to clear my concepts whose output i am unable to understand is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Name 
{
  operator int() 
  {
      std::cout<<"Name's int version called"<<std::endl;
      return 4;
  }
  operator float() 
  {
      std::cout<<"Name's float version called"<<std::endl;
      return 1.1f;
  }
  
};
int main()
{
    
    double a = Name(); //this works and calls Name's float version. But WHY ISN'T THIS AMBIGIOUS?
    long double b = Name();  //this does not work. WHY IS THIS AMBIGIOUS?
    bool c = Name();  //this does not work. WHY IS THIS AMBIGIOUS? 
     
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Tp4l2gH_0) the program works when creating `double a`. But when i try to create objects `b` and `c` it gives error.

My questions are:

1. Why don't we get the ambiguity error for object `a`. That is, among the two **conversion operators** in class `Name`, why the `float` version is chosen over the `int` version.
2. Why/how do we get the ambiguity error for object `b` which is a `long double`. That is just like for `a`, i suspected that the `float` version should have been called but instead we get the error. How is this different from the `double a` case above.
3. Why/how do we get the ambiguity error for object `c` which is `bool`. In this case, I suspected that the `int` version could have been chosen but instead we get an error. How is this different than the `double a` version which works and uses `float` version of conversion function.

I just want to understand why/how the first version works but the other two don't.

Comment: I can see why the `c` case does not work, as it is narrowing, but I'm not sure why `a` is allowed and `b` is not.

Comment: You may want the `language-lawyer` tag on this question, if you want the technical answer from the standard citing chapter & verse.

Comment: IMO Implicit promotion `float` to `double` is a reason, `operator float()` returns double.

Comment: The similar behavior with `operator char()` instead of `operator int()`: `int b = Name();` - ok, `long c = Name();` - ambiguous. `char` is promoted to `int` and `operator char()` returns `int`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentially, skipping over some stuff not relevant in this case, overload resolution is done to choose the user-defined conversion function to initialize the variable and (because there are no other differences between the conversion operators) the best viable one is chosen based on the rank of the standard conversion sequence required to convert the return value of to the variable's type.

---

The conversion `int -> double` is a *floating-integral conversion*, which has rank *conversion*.

The conversion `float -> double` is a *floating-point promotion*, which has rank *promotion*.

The rank *promotion* is better than the rank *conversion*, and so overload resolution will choose `operator float` as the best viable overload.

---

The conversion `int -> long double` is also a *floating-integral conversion*.

The conversion `float -> long double` is *not* a *floating-point promotion* (which only applies for conversion `float -> double`). It is instead a *floating-point conversion* which has rank *conversion*.

Both sequences now have the same standard conversion sequence rank and also none of the tie-breakers (which I won't go through) applies, so overload resolution is ambigious.

---

The conversion `int -> bool` is a *boolean conversion* which has rank *conversion*.

The conversion `float -> bool` is also a *boolean conversion*.

Therefore the same situation as above arises.

---

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion for a full list of the conversion categories and ranks.

---

Although it might seem that a conversion between floating-point types should be considered "better" than a conversion from integral to floating-point type, this is generally not the case.

Comment: See #7.7 and #7.9 in [this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) for the official promotion stuff. Though why `float` -> `long double` is excluded, I'm not sure. (Or even `double` -> `long double`.) Or [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpprom) and [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.double) for the latest online Standard.

Comment: @AdrianMole You could ask the same for integral promotions, which also (mostly) only applies for conversion from smaller types to `int`. It just gives preference to the default promotions that would be done in a C function with unknown parameter type.

Comment: So... you basically need a PhD to know *simple* conversions, promotions and overload resolutions in C++

Answer (score 1):

In this initialization

```
double a = Name();
```

there is used the floating *point promotion*.

The C++ 17 Standard (7.7 Floating-point promotion)

> 1 A prvalue of type float can be converted to a prvalue of type
> double. The value is unchanged. 2 This conversion is called
> floating-point promotion

For the conversion function that returns an object of the type   `int` there is used a conversion that has a less rank than the floating-point promotion.

That is a conversion function with the promotion rank is more viable than a function that has the conversion rank.

In these declarations

```
long double b = Name();
bool c = Name();
```

there are used conversions from the type int and float correspondingly to the type long double and bool. So neither conversion is better.  The both functions have the conversion rank.